# Theory on how to find the equation of a curve given a variable number of data points

Tags: algorithm, math, theory

I have recently started working on a project. One of the problems I ran into was converting changing accelerations into velocity. Accelerations at different points in time are provided through sensors. If you get the equation of these data points, the derivative of a certain time (x) on that equation will be the velocity.

I know how to do this on the computer, but how would I get the equation to start with? I have searched around but I have not found any existing programs that can form an equation given a set of points. In the past, I have created a neural net algorithm to form an equation, but it takes an incredibly long time to run.

If someone can link me a program or explain the process of doing this, that would be fantastic.

Sorry if this is in the wrong forum. I would post into math, but a programming background will be needed to know the realm of possibility of what a computer can do quickly.

Comment: Investigate least squares fits, Lagrangian interpolation, Kalman filters, that sort of thing.  Common numerical methods will answer it.

Comment: @duffymo OK, thank you for your comment. Could you expound on what you mean by common numerical methods? And I'll be sure to look those up.

Comment: I don't think you want what you say you want. First, to go from acceleration to velocity you **integrate**, not differentiate. Second, while symbolic integration is possible in some cases, why not use a numerical integration? There are loads of well-studied numerical integration methods.

Comment: I agree that numerical integration is what you want to go from acceleration to velocity. If you want to code it yourself, a couple simple methods are the trapezoid rule or the slightly more complicated Simpson's rule. Otherwise you could try using a numerical package for whatever language you are using. As an aside, "numerical solutions" are just solutions to problems done on a computer using numbers only, rather than math symbols you would use when solving the problem by hand--those are "analytic solutions". :)

Comment: @eigenchris Are there any online examples of using numeric integration to go from acceleration to velocity? And thanks a bunch for your comment. It really helped my understand.

Comment: I don't get it. This seems trivial. You have a set of observations of accelerations. Can't you integrate discretely, a.k.a. sum? For example, give accelerations 1.3, 1.9, -0.5, 2.1, 1.4, -0.2, -1.9 Then the speed is 1.3, 3.2, 2.7, 4.8, 6.2, 6.0, 4.1. What am I missing? If you need to interpolate between points, just do that then integrate. Then curve fit. I have to be missing something.

Comment: @JasonN: There are times when that simple method of numerical integration will have unacceptably poor performance which is why there are more complicated methods such as the trapezoid rule, Simpson's rule, and higher degree analogues. In case the sample points are too clumped, say at 1.00, 1.01, 1.02, and 2.00, 2.01, 2.02, then numerical integration is not appropriate and using regression is reasonable.

Comment: @DouglasZare I guess I'm aware of those issue with arrival frequency and scattered observations, but the poster's data seem to arrive often and maybe approximately equally spaced? I wasn't thinking that the you would need to interpolate the acceleration (I'm finance, not mechanical engineering). If I had to do this, I probably just make a bunch of splines instead of looking for a single formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started out as a comment but ended up being too big.

Just to make sure you're familiar with the terminology...

**Differentiation** takes a function *f(t)* and spits out a new function *f'(t)* that tells you how *f(t)* changes with time (i.e. *f'(t)* gives the slope of *f(t)* at time *t*). This takes you from displacement to velocity or from velocity to acceleration.

**Integreation** takes a function *f(t)* and spits out a new function *F(t)* which measures the area under the function *f(t)* from the beginning of time up until a given point *t*. What's not obvious at first is that integration is actually the **reverse** of differentiation, a fact called the [The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). So integration takes you from acceleration to velocity or velocity to displacement.

You don't need to understand the rules of calculus to do numerical integration. The simplest (and most naive) method for integrating a function numerically is just by approximating the area by dividing it up into small slices between time points and summing the area of rectangles. This approximating sum is called a **Reimann sum**.

[image]

As you can see, this tends to really overshoot and undershoot certain parts of the function. A more accurate but still very simple method is the **trapezoid rule**, which also approximates the function with a series of slices, except the tops of the slices are straight lines between the function values rather than constant values.

[image]

Still more complicated, but yet a better approximation, is Simpson's rules, which approximates the function with parabolas between time points.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tutorvista.com](http://images.tutorvista.com/cms/images/45/composite-simpsons-rule.jpeg))</sub>

You can think of each of these methods as getting a better approximation of the integral because they each use more information about the function. The first method uses just one data point per area (a constant flat line), the second method uses two data points per area (a straight line), and the third method uses three data points per area (a parabola).

You could read up on the math behind these methods [here](http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/4/approx.1/) or in the first page of [this pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20100613180044/http://dynsys.uml.edu/tutorials/Integration_Differentiation/Int-diff_tutorial_011405.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments that numerical integration is probably what you want. In case you still want a function going through your data, let me further argue against doing that.

It's usually a bad idea to find a curve that goes exactly through some given points. In almost any applied math context you have to accept that there is a little noise in the inputs, and a curve going exactly through the points may be very sensitive to noise. This can produce garbage outputs. Finding a curve going exactly through a set of points is asking for [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) to get a function that memorizes rather than understands the data, and does not generalize.

For example, take the points (0,0), (1,1), (2,4), (3,9), (4,16), (5,25), (6,36). These are seven points on y=x^2, which is fine. The value of x^2 at x=-1 is 1. Now what happens if you replace (3,9) with (2.9,9.1)? There is a sixth order polynomial passing through all 7 points,

```
4.66329x - 8.87063x^2 + 7.2281x^3 - 2.35108x^4 + 0.349747x^5 - 0.0194304x^6.
```

[image: graph of y=x^2 and interpolating polynomial for modified data]

The value of this at x=-1 is -23.4823, very far from 1. While the curve looks ok between 0 and 2, in other examples you can see large oscillations between the data points.

Once you accept that you want an approximation, not a curve going exactly through the points, you have what is known as a [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) problem. There are many types of regression. Typically, you choose a set of functions and a way to measure how well a function approximates the data. If you use a simple set of functions like lines ([linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)), you just find the best fit. If you use a more complicated family of functions, you should use [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29) to penalize overly complicated functions such as high degree polynomials with large coefficients that memorize the data. If you either use a simple family or regularization, the function tends not to change much when you add or withhold a few data points, which indicates that it is a meaningful trend in the data.

Comment: Hmm... how would it work with a set of predetermined functions? In my scenario, the data points will come at pseudorandom. It can be likened to the acceleration of a car. You can't really predict before hand how the acceleration will change. Also, how would I use numeric integration.

Comment: @Justin Chang: When I say choose a set of functions, I mean you have a family of functions with some parameters. For example, linear functions might be parametrized by the constant term and the slope. Then you find the parameters which minimize the measure of errors (called the loss). If you feel the data is localized, so that knowing the values around 0 tell you nothing about the values around 100, then use things like sums of localized pieces, or radial basis functions. If you look up numerical integration and try it and still have questions, ask another question about it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, integrating accelerometer data to get velocity is a numerically unstable problem. For most applications, your error will diverge far too soon to get results of any practical value.

Recall that:

[image: v(t) = \int a(t)]

So:

[image]

However well you fit a function to your accelerometer data, you will still essentially be doing a piecewise interpolation of the underlying acceleration function:

[image: v_{T_{n}} = v_{T_{0}} + \int_{T_{0}}^{T_{1}} a_{0}(t):dt + \int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} a_{1}(t):dt + ... +\int_{T_{n-1}}^{T_{n}} a_{n-1}(t):dt]

Where the error terms from each integration will add!

Typically you will see wildly inaccurate results after just [a few seconds](http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity).